# Decrypting an encrypted MySQL 8 field, encrypted by Rails, from php

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Rails 7
MySQL 8
php 8.1
```

I have a model Author, and in it:

```
encrypts: address
```

So when information is saved in the authors table, the address field is automatically encrypted by ActiveRecord.

Within a rails console, I can do:

```
author = Author.find_by_id(5)
```

and then:

```
author.address
```

Which will give me the decrypted value of author.address

In the credentials file, I have:

```
active_record_encryption:
  primary_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  deterministic_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  key_derivation_salt: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I need to develop an interface in php, that can retrieve and decrypt the address information from the authors table. Is this possible?

I know how to use mysqli, it's the decryption I am having trouble with.

Comment: Have you found a way to do this? I'm looking for a solution to do exactly this.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a solution